# How can I tell why TFS ran a build?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a xaml build definition that has its trigger set to run nightly and the "Build if nothing changes" is unchecked. If I run a build during the day and then no-one checks in for the remainder of the day, for some reason, TFS is building the same changeset at the trigger's time. This seems to be happening with several different build definitions for different branches. Is there a way to tell why it is building? I updated the TFS Server to the current version (Tfs2017.Update3) several months ago, to be honest, I did not check or notice if this has been happening since I've updated to TFS 2017 sometime last year. Are there any TFS database tables to check to see what triggers a build?

Here's my current setup:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the workspace section for any other build definition that would be CI (build on check-in) is set to the specific folder where that build should get files from.  The default was $/projectname which is start that build anytime ANY files change anywhere in that project.  You need to make you workspace section very specific when using CI or you will have unintended consequences like you are seeing.  [image: Source settings for xaml builds]

Comment: We have 2 build defs to the same branch. One is for CI the other via a trigger, the one I'm talking about here, it is set to go off nightly that takes about 3.5-4hrs, this is the build that rolls up all the installers. Sometimes we run this during the day to grab an installer. The issue at hand is the triggered build will run again when there were no other checkins. You can see that it rebuilds the same changeset. Again not a major issue but we have systems that autoupdate for QA in the morning - these are being uninstalled and installed with a new version even though nothing has changed.

Comment: So the fact that you trigger it manually during the day and the schedule are two different things.  The schedule will check if there was a change between the last Scheduled build and when it's supposed to start.  If there is a new changeset (which there is) it will trigger.  The fact that you ran it during the day manually doesn't change that.